# How to have CD/CI for and S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cdn, cicd

Question here more about gathering ideas on how to manage an S3…
So currently what I have is CI/CD job that is executed when I push something to a specific git repo and picks all the contents in that repo and pushes them to an S3 bucket. This bucket then has a CDN on top and that’s all good.

Having this git repo is great because it allows me to keep the CDN versionized and makes sure no one person can screw it up by mistake.

Now… I’m about to add some 50G of images into that CDN, which doing it in git :laught its not a great idea xD
So I wonder, how do you guys manage larger CDN’s?

Thanks!

Comment: Do those 50GB of images ever change? Surely you don't need a CI/CD setup to automate regular updates of those images.

Comment: Main issue (not optimize way) is transfer those 50GB of images to S3 per every commit, not storing this data in S3 under CDN at all, right? 
As an alternate you can upload all those data once and using S3 object versions (so you still keeping versioning of your CDN) and also you can modify your CI/CD to have 2 jobs:

1. Uploading difference (instead of whole content) to S3 - per every commit
2. Upload all the content to the S3 - this job maybe should be run manually only for init upload - but in that case you not necessary need having it as CI/CD - simple bash script will be better